# ¿Cómo crear sitemaps de manera periódica en Laravel7?

Tags: laravel, digitalocean, sitemap

Verán, estoy usando el paquete spatie/laravel-sitemap para crearme un sitemap. Me ha funcionado perfecto para crear el primer sitemap, pero no logro hacer que se actualice periódicamente con los nuevos enlaces que agrego a mi página.

Lo primero que hice fue crearme un artisan command en el cual escribí:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;

class GenerateSitemap extends Command
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sitemap:generate';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Generate the sitemap.';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // modify this to your own needs
        SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
            ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
    }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, ejecute en consola el comando:

```
php artisan sitemap:generate
```

Y con eso logré generar mi sitemap, hasta ahí todo correcto. En la documentación decía que si quería que se genera un nuevo sitemap periódicamente, sin la necesidad de estar ejecutando este comando, podría agregar  en el kernel de la consola esta linea de código.

```
// app/Console/Kernel.php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    ...
    $schedule->command('sitemap:generate')->daily();
    ...
}
```

Y aunque he configurado que me genere uno nuevo a diario, ya ha pasado 3 días y no se actualiza el sitemap, por más que he agregado nuevos enlaces.

Mi proyecto está subido en Digital Oceans a través de Laravel Forge. ¿O es qué tengo que cambiar alguna configuración ahí para que se pueda ejecutar periódicamente los sitemaps?

De antemano, cualquier ayuda estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110321/discussion-on-question-by-victor-arana-flores-como-crear-sitemaps-de-manera-per).

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución.

El problema radicaba que en forge había programado el scheduled con el siguiente comando:

```
php /home/forge/default/artisan schedule:run
```

Pero debí programarlo con este comando

```
php /home/forge/nombre_de_mi_sitio.com/artisan schedule:run
```

Ya que mi sitio no lleva el nombre de default.

Ya lo probé y está funcionando a la perfección.